# Django ORM (1.11): How to get the first element of a list of related objects that matches a criteria, within an annotation

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have the following annotation:

```py
name=Case(
    When(
        related_model__confirmed=F("confirmed"),
        then=F("related_model__name")
    ),
    default=None,
    output_field=CharField()
)
```

It has an obvious problem: it increases the size of the queryset.

Not only that, I want the annotation to be set to either `rel_model_a__model_b__name` (the first time the condition is met), or `None` if the condition is never met.

Any way I can do this?

---

EDIT 1:

This is a (*very*) simplified version of the source code for both models involved.

```py
from django.db import models

class Sheet(models.Model):
    generated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    confirmed = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sheet = models.ForeignKey(Sheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sheet_brands")
    confirmed = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)

queryset = Sheet.objects.annotate(name=Case(
    When(
        sheet_brands__confirmed=F("confirmed"),
        then=F("sheet_brands__name")
    ),
    default=None,
    output_field=CharField()
)
```

Comment: Those are all `ForeignKey`s?

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem does the edit make it clearer?